PyDSTool Library Issue in Colab but Import error
I have installed the PyDSTool library on Colab but still receiving import error. The error is given
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fb28dd33b337> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import PyDSTool

4 frames
/content/notebooks/PyDSTool/common.py in <module>
     14 from scipy.optimize import minpack
     15 # In future, will convert these specific imports to be referred as npy.X
---> 16 from numpy import Inf, NaN, atleast_1d, clip, less, greater, logical_or, \
     17      searchsorted, isfinite, shape, mat, sign, any, all, sometrue, alltrue, \
     18      array, swapaxes, zeros, ones, finfo, double, exp, log, \

ImportError: cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

